# Beautiful Soup default decode charset?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I have a huge set of web pages with different encodings, and I try to parse it using Beautiful Soup.

As I have noticed, BS detects encoding using meta-charset or xml-encoding tags. But there are documents with no such tags or typos in charset name - and BS fails on all of them. I suppose it's default guess is utf-8, which is wrong. Luckily, all such pages (or nearly all of them) have the same encoding. Is there any way to set it as default?

I've also tried to grep charset and use iconv to utf8 first - it works nice, and provides perfectly readable utf-8 encoded output, but BS `BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read())` sometimes (rarely, like 0.05% of all files) randomly fails on it with

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte *** in position ***: invalid start byte
```

The basic reason here, for my mind, is that while actual encoding is already utf-8, meta-tags still state the previous one, so BS is confused. It has really strange behavior here - like it works smoothly when I delete one or another random character (like '-' or '*' etc. -  not any wicked strange one) - so I gave up on it, and I really wish to proceed with native Beautiful Soup decoding, while it is also a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup will indeed use an educated guess using a character detection library. That process *can* be wrong; removing just one character can indeed radically change the outcome for certain types of documents.

You can override this guess by specifying an input codec:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, from_encoding=codec)
```

You could use exception handling here to only apply the manual codec when decoding failed:

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, from_encoding=codec)
```

Also see the [*Encodings* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) of the BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: The problem is that I need default encoding only for documents >> with no such tags or typos in charset name; and "from_encoding=codec", as I understand, forces BS to always use that codec.

Comment: @user3702700: which is where the exception handling comes in.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is really valuable for me. But unfortunately, it comes out there is no exception thrown in this case. For now I ended up modifying encodings lists in dammit.py for sections "As a last resort" & "As an absolute last resort". There were utf-8 and windows-1252, and so the final guess was windows-1252, which was wrong. But it will be really more preferable to achieve this without source code modifications.

Comment: There is no generic solution to identify incorrectly tagged character sets. Some tools like `chardet` do a fairly good job, but ultimately, there will always be some evil genius who finds a way to put the wrong tag in such a way that only manual inspection, hard work, and a lot of guessing is the only solution.

Comment: @tripleee an even more evil genius will combine different encodings into a single document.  Then there's no choice but [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).